# Why does tesseract OSD gives only 90,270,0 etc? why not random skew angles?

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

When i try to identify skew angle using tesseract osd feature (using pytesseract image_to_osd()), i always get skew result of 0,90,270. However, my images have random skews like 40 degree, 55 degree, etc. Doesn't tesseract support skew angles other than 0,90,270?

Answer (score 0):

tesseract is good at working with documentations and basicly screenshots,but u can make it work with [opencv](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) library's deskew option

personally i recommend using [easyocr](https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR) which is GPU based engine works good, quick and easy, end to end engine